# Do some browsers block to create image/xml from svg string using new Blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, blob

I have some code for generate SVG image using SVG string.. when i run this code, all goes well, but some people that try my apps told to me that the SVG/image is not show. What i want to know is there are any browser or some settings or proxy or security that block to create SVG image from SVG string using Blob??

this is my code (to generate SVG image)

```
renderSvg = (svgString) => {
    let blob = new Blob([svgString], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return (
      <img
        src={url}
        style={{
          border: "2px solid #aeaeae",
          borderRadius: "5px",
          padding: "5px",
        }}
        alt="svg"
      />
    );
  };
```

Comment: Probably old Internet Explorer versions.

Comment: What is `svgString`? I.e, how do you extract the markup? Do you ensure it always contains all that is necessary to make it a proper standalone document (e.g an `xmlns` attribute on the root <svg>)